# csrf session token missing flask

Tags: html, flask, csrf, flask-wtforms

I am trying to use csrf protection on my forms but I always get an error saying I am missing the csrf session token.

I dont know whats wrong with my code, maybe someone here can help me understand what I am doing wrong.

my code:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
csrf = CSRFProtect(app)

@app.route("/reserve", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def reserve():
   if request.method == "GET" :
       return render_template("reserve.html", csrf_token=generate_csrf())


<form id="Reserve" action="/reserve" method="post">
   <!-- csrf protection -->
   <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}"/>
   <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
   <button type="submit">
        Submit
   </button>
</form>
```

I have tried using: `<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>`
but it still wont work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to set a [secret key](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/config/#SECRET_KEY) for the application.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template, request
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'your secret here'
csrf = CSRFProtect(app)

@app.route('/reserve', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def reserve():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('reserve.html')
```

```
<form action="/reserve" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
   <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I did, just forgot to mention it.